# Not able to see histograms and distributions in TensorBoard configured as a callback from Keras

Tags: keras, tensorboard

The TensorBoard call back itself seems to work ok! I am able to see the Graph and events (loss and accuracy charts).
I am not able to see histograms and distributions though.
histogram_freq is set to 1.
And callback looks somewhat like below...

```
keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/path/to/logs', histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior.  I'm surprised you're the only one to mention it so far.  What versions of TF and Keras are you using?  I'm seeing the behavior with Keras 1.2.1 and TF 0.12.

Comment: Yes same version Keras 1.2.1 and TF 0.12.

Answer (score 4):

The TensorBoard callback creates a self.merged layer with nodes comprised of the histograms and images, but it only attempts to write this summary info if model.validation_data is defined. If you are using fit_generator with a generator for the validation data, validation_data is set to None, and therefore the images and histograms are never written.

Comment: If you explain more about your answer it would be a great answer.

Comment: I am not using fit_generator

Comment: Likewise, not using fit_generator but still not getting anything

Comment: You can also use `validation_split`.